# Jquery + drop down dates to store date and time - formatting issue

Tags: php, jquery, date, drop-down-menu, strtotime

My problem: when I combine my Jquery datepicker calendar input and the drop downs I put beside it to capture hours, minutes, and AM/PM I can't get the proper date to print out.

Here is my php code:

```
echo protect($_POST['truck_arrive'])." - truck arrive<br>";
echo protect($_POST['truck_arrive_hours'])." - truck arrive hours<br>";
echo protect($_POST['truck_arrive_mins'])." - truck arrive mins<br>";
echo protect($_POST['truck_arrive_ampm'])." - truck arrive ampm<br>";

$truck_arrive_comb = protect($_POST['truck_arrive']).protect($_POST['truck_arrive_hours']).protect($_POST['truck_arrive_mins']).protect($_POST['truck_arrive_ampm']);

echo $truck_arrive_comb." - truck arrive combination<br>";
echo strtotime($truck_arrive_comb)." - truck arrive combination string to time<br>";
echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($truck_arrive_comb))." - truck arrive combination string to time date format<br>";

//$truck_arrive = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime($truck_arrive_comb));
$truck_arrive = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime(protect($_POST['truck_arrive'])));
echo $truck_arrive." - truck arrive date format<br>";
```

and it outputs this:

```
01/16/2013 - truck arrive
01 - truck arrive hours
04 - truck arrive mins
AM - truck arrive ampm
01/16/20130104AM - truck arrive combination
- truck arrive combination string to time
1969-12-31 07:00:00 - truck arrive combination string to time date format
2013-01-16 12:00:00 - truck arrive date format
```

Comment: Can we see a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I'm not sure what a fiddle is?  This code is called after data on a previous form is submitted.  I figured I was doing something wrong with my order of how I combined the date and hours/minutes?

Comment: oh I see the link now, but can you put php code in jfiddle?

Comment: No PHP on JSfiddle. But since PHP is processed before the page is served, you can use the output in the Fiddle.

Comment: The output is already in the question... no need for a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplification of what you can use, just replace hard coded values with appropriate `$_POST`:

```
/* hard coded values for test*/
$hours=1;
$minutes=40;
$am_pm='am';

$hours = $am_pm == 'pm' ? $hours +12 : $hours;
$dateTime=strtotime('01/16/2013')  ;/* returns seconds*/

$timeInSeconds= ($minutes * 60) + ($hours*3600);
/* add time in seconds to date in seconds*/
$totalSeconds= $dateTime + $timeInSeconds;

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$totalSeconds );
```

WIll need to modify if timezone needs to be considered.

An alternate approach is to parse the time and date strings into same format as above output and pass that to `strtotime()` or simply match output that `date()` creates using the strings

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  I have to convert it to seconds before it will let me use strtotime().  I guess my issue was when I just used the jquery datepicker I could stick that information directly into strtotime().  THANK YOU!

Comment: nothing simple about dates ... lots to consider like timezones, daylight savings etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$truck_arrive_comb` is an invalid format for `strtotime()`

PLease see here [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)